# Querying Geohashes in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing, geofirestore

Recently I've been playing around with [Geohashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and Firestore. 
My todo scenario is to have a collection of documents (restaurants) and each restaurant will have list of Geohashes which delivers to.

I want to avoid adding the geoashes in the document restaurant as the document can be many times bigger than it should be.

The initial idea is to have all of the geohashes in a subcollection of the restaurant document but I found out its not possible to perform queries in subcollection of documents.

The second idea was to extract the geohashes to top level in a collection of delivery areas.

```
document:{ restaurantName: "aRestaurant", 
deliveryArea: Arraylist<String> }
```

The problem in this scenario is that I will get back a list of restaurant names, where then I need to query the restaurants collection to get them and as far as I know I cannot perform OR operations in the queries.

It is my first time playing around with document databases and Firestore. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to avoid adding the geoashes in the document restaurant as the document can be many times bigger than it should be.

Yes, don't do that because documents have limits. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but if you are using complex objects, this is not an option.

> The initial idea is to have all of the geohashes in a subcollection of the restaurant document but I found out its not possible to perform queries in subcollection of documents.

It's is a good solution. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- restaurants (collection)
        |
        --- restaurantId (document)
                |
                --- geohashes (collection)
                      |
                      --- geohashId (document)
                            |
                            --- //details about the location
```

So a query that can allow you get all `geohash` objects of a particular restaurant, will work perfectly fine.

> The second idea was to extract the geohashes to top level in a collection of delivery areas

Is not a bad solution, but you should create an extra `get()` call, to get restaurant details but even if do this, is not a bad call, there is no problem regarding nested queries in Firestore. There is no need for `OR` operation.

**Edit:** According to your comment, yes, you're right, you cannot query the database to get back restaurant objects but we have here a work around too. In this case you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup, by addining an new collection like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- geohashes (collection)
         |
         --- geohashId (document)
               |
               --- geohashRestaurants (collection)
                        |
                        --- restaurantId
                               |
                               --- //restaurant details
```

This tehnique is called `denormalization` which as you can see implies duplicating data. But you need to know that there is no problem with duplicating data, when it comes to Firebase. This is a quite common practice and for that, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). Is for Firebase realtime database but same principle apply to Cloud Firestore as well.

When you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the confirmations. 
Now the big question is that if I follow any of those ideas, I cannot query the geohashes ( collection ) to get back restaurant ( documents ).
` db.collection(restaurants).get().where(geohash == ABCD123)`

The above query is what Im after, and quering sub collection is not available in firestore unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Our original GeoFire library for the Firebase Realtime Database solved precisely this problem by having a separate top-level node for the geohashes. Each key under that node would typically correspond to the key of an actual entity in another top-level node.

So something like:

```
locations
  key1: { g: "sa7ads", l: [ 14.5232, -156.17843 ] },
  key2: { g: "fds347", l: [ -127.172, 167.1324 ] }
restaurants
  key1: { name: "This is the first restaurant", ... },
  key2: { name: "This is the second restaurant", ... },
```

With this structure, you perform a geoquery on `/locations` and then read the additional information of each restaurant in range from `/restaurants/$key`. That scaled quite well.

I'd recommend the same approach with Cloud Firestore. You'd have two top-level collections: one with the (smaller) location data, and one with the (bigger) additional data about each restaurant. This reduces the amount of data you read, although you will end up reading more documents. You'll have to balance these two (bandwidth vs. document reads) off against each other.

A few months ago I gave a [talk about performing geoqueries on Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q) that might be worth checking out.

Comment: Hi Frank, your talk was amazing! 
I did have a look in GeoFire library and looks really good. Though one of the questions that came up while watching your talk, what will happen if for example one of the restaurant wants to change in delivery locations? You will need to get all the documents(geohashes) that contain it, alter them and save them. It sounds like a big operation for a serverless infrastructure :/ ( I guess a cloud function could come handy in this situation )